# I'm in a place where

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms, idiomatic-language

> The truth is that things have been a little difficult for me after my accident last year, but now I finally feel that **I'm in a place** where I can enjoy life again, so I'm great.

Is "in a place" perfectly natural here referring to my mental condition and not a physical place?

Answer (score 1):

In general, "in a place" could be interpreted either way, depending on context. If there is no context referring to a physical place (like your sentence), then I would interpret as referring to one's mental condition. (I think "*at* a place" would also be an equivalent substitute.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It is quite clear that you are referring to your situation and not your physical surroundings.